# Jquery .remove element if selection made, but then append back

Tags: jquery, text, onchange

I have a form that changes dynamically using jQuery depending on what dropdown boxes choices are selected.

In this particular case I have a drop down called "Event type" where the user chooses either "wedding" or "private party". This choice then affects the content in the next dropdown which is "Choose a Package", there are 6 packages to choose from for "weddings", say packages a, b, c, d, e and f but for "private parties" only packages a, c, and e.

I've been using the .remove function to get rid of options b, d and f when "private parties" is selected - however if I then go and select "weddings" after selecting "private parties" (Say if a user selects the wrong choice by mistake) - the options I removed don't come back.

Here is my code I am using (I also have to change the name of the packages which you'll see mixed into the code below):

```
$('#eventType').change(function() {
var eventTypeName = $("#eventType option:selected");

if (eventTypeName.is('[name="private_party"]') ) {
    $('#band_type_choices option[name="acoustic"]').text('Lace');//lace
    $('#band_type_choices option[name="jazz"]').text('Satin');//satin
    $('#band_type_choices option[name="acoustic_jazz"]').remove();//lace+satin
    $('#band_type_choices option[name="party"]').text('Silk');//silk
    $('#band_type_choices option[name="acoustic_party"]').remove();//lace+silk
    $('#band_type_choices option[name="jazz_party"]').remove();//satin+silk
    $('#band_type_choices option[name="acoustic_jazz_party"]').text('Brocade');//brocade

}
```

});

Can anyone tell me how I dynamically put these options back again when my user selects a different options for event type
Thanks

Comment: use `$('...').attr("disabled","disabled");` instead `remove();`

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't solve my problem as the option don't become "enabled" when I switch pack to "weddings"

Comment: when you switch back, do this `$('...').attr("disabled",false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.remove()` will completely remove the options from the list. Instead use `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` to disable the options list.

Then when the user selects `weddings` renable the menu by making `.attr('disabled', 'false')`

Much better way is to hide the option using `.hide()` instead of `remove()`

Else you need to reconstruct the options menu twice for each selection. It will result in duplicate of code.

Comment: Thanks for this, I managed to get the result using .hide() and .show() which is something you originally posted, is this not a good way to do it?

Comment: You can do that way. I was trying with different options in jsbin :)